# How do I remove a kernel from Fedora for good?

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, linux-kernel, grub2

I am running Fedora 32 and I want to remove the new 5.7 kernel since it is causing some problems.

I have tried:

```
sudo dnf remove kernel-*5.7.10-201.fc32.x86_64
```

And it did remove something but **the kernel is still there in the GRUB menu and is strangely fully bootable.**

How do I remove it for good ? **I want it gone from the GRUB menu and completely from my system.**

Running the command:

```
dnf list installed kernel-* | grep -i 5.7
```

proves the kernel 5.7 is still present:

```
kernel-core.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
kernel-devel.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
kernel-headers.x86_64 5.7.10-200.fc32
kernel-modules.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
```

How do I remove these and how do I get rid of it from GRUB ?

Note:
Running something like:

```
sudo dnf remove kernel-core.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
sudo dnf remove kernel-core.x86_64.5.7.10-201.fc32
sudo dnf remove kernel-core.5.7.10-201.fc32.x86_64
```

All give errors.

The errors are as follows:

```
$ sudo dnf remove kernel-core.x86_64 5.7.10-201.fc32
No match for argument: 5.7.10-201.fc32
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: kernel-core
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)


$ sudo dnf remove kernel-core.x86_64.5.7.10-201.fc32
No match for argument: kernel-core.x86_64.5.7.10-201.fc32
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!


$ sudo dnf remove kernel-core.5.7.10-201.fc32.x86_64
No match for argument: kernel-core.5.7.10-201.fc32.x86_64
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that version is not the one currently running? what does `uname -r` say?

Comment: @schaiba It says : `5.7.10-201.fc32.x86_64`

Comment: @schaiba That is I can boot into the kernel after it has been removed. Which is to say is weird.

Comment: So, you can boot into a kernel version that you want to keep, yes?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes. I had to use rpm to get the full name.

Answer (score 7):

It seems DNF does not give the full name of the package that would be needed by `dnf remove` to remove the kernel.

For that it is better to use `rpm`.

This is the command that worked for me:

```
sudo dnf remove $(rpm -qa | grep ^kernel | grep 5\.7)
```

Comment: I get "Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: kernel-core (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)"; With --skip-broken: "Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: kernel-core"

Comment: in my case that resulted in fedora wanting to remove also emacs, luarocks and suchlike packages. I realized it's the kernel-headers package that's contentious, and `sudo dnf remove $(rpm -qa | grep ^kernel | grep 6\.5 | grep -v headers)` worked as intended.